# Highlight all text in TextField upon click JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, textarea, textfield

I'm making a JavaFX application and upon launch, the TextField has default text that says "Please enter this value", the user is supposed to delete said text and enter a value. However, it is quite a pain to click, drag, and highlight all the text each time. **Is there a way to make it so when the user clicks on the TextField, it automatically highlights all the text for easy deletion, but ONLY when the text is equal to the default message?** I researched this and couldn't find anything, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why not use prompt text, instead of some default text?

Comment: Wow I'm stupid, didn't even realize that existed. Thanks 

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To do what you explicitly ask, you can use

```
textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
    if (isNowFocused && DEFAULT_TEXT.equals(textField.getText())) {
        textField.selectAll();
    }
});
```

But it is probably better to use `promptText` for this functionality anyway:

```
textField.setPromptText(DEFAULT_TEXT);
```

Comment: Awesome, I really appreciate it. I'm fine with using prompt text, but there are two reasons why I originally preferred to use default text: the CSS styling doesn't affect the prompt text, and if I use prompt text then the first textfield (there are 2) is automatically focused upon launch which hides the text. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @JoshNarsu You can change the color of the prompt text with the `-fx-prompt-text-fill` property (though I'm not sure about other properties: you could try independently setting styles for when the text field is focused and when it is not focused). You can also get around the prompt text being hidden when the text field is focused (but empty) with a bit of CSS magic.

Answer (score 2):

This line works fine for me

```
textField.setOnMouseClicked(e -> textField.selectAll());
```