# Highlight all text in TextField upon FIRST click JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, textfield, highlight

How can I make my text field (JavaFX) exactly the same as the search bar of Google Chrome above. That means, if I click once on it, it marks everything, but if I click again, I am exactly where I clicked.

Example:

Start:

[image]

First click:

[image]

Click a second time:

[image]

**EDIT**

This is what i tried:

```
textField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, wasFocused, isNowFocused) -> {
                if (isNowFocused) {
                    textField.selectAll();
                }
                if (wasFocused) {
                    textField.deselect();
                }
            });
```

But with this code, when I click the first time, everything is selected and gets deselected again immediately.

Comment: Have you tried adding a listener to the focused property and selects all text when focus is gained? If not, try that (or something similar), and post a [mre] if it doesn't work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Highlight all text in TextField upon click JavaFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43984717/highlight-all-text-in-textfield-upon-click-javafx)

Comment: @codeflush.dev no, it didn't answered my question.

Comment: What's the purpose of the second `if` clause? Doesn't it do what you want if you remove that?

Comment: @James_D yes I can remove this, but the behaviour remains the same. When i click on it (textfield is not in focus), the text get selected und immeditaley deselected.

Comment: Hmm. I guess the default behavior is happening after the behavior you're adding (which is strange). You can probably wrap the call to `selectAll()` in a  `Platform.runLater()`, but that is not very satisfactory.

Comment: When i wrap it in Platform.runLater(), then it behaves like it should.

Comment: @Gregor Yes, I expect it to. But it's a pretty horrible hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `MouseEvent` and `EventFilter`:

```
TextField textField = new TextField("This is a test");

textField.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED, e -> {
    if (textField.getSelectedText().equals(textField.getText())) {
        textField.deselect();
    } else if (textField.getSelectedText().isEmpty()) {
        textField.selectAll();
        e.consume();
    } 
});
```